# Tables side-by-side (again)

Tags: tables, captions, minipage, labels, sidebyside

I know this type of question was already posted a ton of times, but I'm upon this for some days and I can't get it working properly.

I need to put two tables side-by-side, aligned to the top, and they both should have separated captions and references.

I went this far, but the tables won't be together.

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{.55\textwidth}
%\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{7cm}|c}
\textbf{A - Fator de correção da rotação}                      & \textbf{dB} \\
\textless 600 rpm                                              & -5          \\
\textgreater 600 rps e \textless 1500 rpm                      & -2          \\
\textgreater 1500 rpm                                          & 0           \\ \hline
\textbf{B - Fator de correção do combustível}                  & \textbf{dB} \\
Diesel e gás natural                                           & 0           \\
Gás natural                                                    & -3          \\ \hline
\textbf{C - Fator de disposição dos cilindros}                 & \textbf{dB} \\
Em linha                                                       & 0           \\
Em V e Radial                                                  & -1          \\ \hline
\textbf{D - Fator de correção de admissão e ar}                & \textbf{dB} \\
Admissão de ar para o roots blower não dutada e não silenciada & +3          \\
Outros tipos de admissão (com ou sem turbo compressor)         & 0          
\end{tabular}
%\caption{...}
\label{Tab:Corr}
%\end{table}
\end{minipage}\qquad

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{.35\textwidth}
%\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} }
 Frequência central da banda de oitava [$Hz$] & Correção ruído de Exaustão [$dB$] & Correção ruído de Admissão [$dB$] \\ 
 \hline
 $31,5$ & $-5$ & $-4$\\  
 $63$ & $-9$ & $-11$\\  
 $125$ & $-3$ & $-13$\\
 $250$ & $-7$ & $-13$\\
 $5.00$ & $-15$ & $-12$\\
 $1.000$ & $-19$ & $-9$\\
 $2.000$ & $-25$ & $-8$\\
 $4.000$ & $-35$ & $-9$\\
 $8.000$ & $-43$ & $-17$\\
\end{tabular}
%\caption{...}
\label{Tab:Exaust}
%\end{table}
\end{minipage}
```

which gives

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you remove the blank line between the minipages?

Comment: Please make your example code compilable. Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: Please use the `siunitx` package for units. They should not be italicized...

Comment: You might want to replace `\qquad` by `\hfill`

Comment: @cmhughes, that solves the problem of they not being side-by-side, thanks. But they're still not aligned to the top, and I can't reference and caption them. What would you suggest?

Comment: @leandriis, I'm sorry I forgot that. I used **\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}** and **\usepackage{array}**.

Comment: @LucasVieira: Are you sure the two tables will fit side by side into the available textwidth? Do you also use the `geometry` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple of options that will hopefully help to display your tables as you'd like.

### Option 1: small tweaks to your code

This option has just a few small tweaks to your code, the output is:

[image: screenshot of options 1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.55\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{your caption goes here}
        \label{Tab:Corr}
        \begin{tabular}{p{7cm}|c}
            \textbf{A - Fator de correção da rotação}                      & \textbf{dB} \\
            \textless 600 rpm                                              & -5          \\
            \textgreater 600 rps e \textless 1500 rpm                      & -2          \\
            \textgreater 1500 rpm                                          & 0           \\ \hline
            \textbf{B - Fator de correção do combustível}                  & \textbf{dB} \\
            Diesel e gás natural                                           & 0           \\
            Gás natural                                                    & -3          \\ \hline
            \textbf{C - Fator de disposição dos cilindros}                 & \textbf{dB} \\
            Em linha                                                       & 0           \\
            Em V e Radial                                                  & -1          \\ \hline
            \textbf{D - Fator de correção de admissão e ar}                & \textbf{dB} \\
            Admissão de ar para o roots blower não dutada e não silenciada & +3          \\
            Outros tipos de admissão (com ou sem turbo compressor)         & 0
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.35\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{your other caption}
        \label{Tab:Exaust}
        \begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} }
            Frequência central da banda de oitava [$Hz$] & Correção ruído de Exaustão [$dB$] & Correção ruído de Admissão [$dB$] \\
            \hline
            $31,5$                                       & $-5$                              & $-4$                              \\
            $63$                                         & $-9$                              & $-11$                             \\
            $125$                                        & $-3$                              & $-13$                             \\
            $250$                                        & $-7$                              & $-13$                             \\
            $5.00$                                       & $-15$                             & $-12$                             \\
            $1.000$                                      & $-19$                             & $-9$                              \\
            $2.000$                                      & $-25$                             & $-8$                              \\
            $4.000$                                      & $-35$                             & $-9$                              \\
            $8.000$                                      & $-43$                             & $-17$                             \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Option 2: booktabs and siunitx

This option adds the `booktabs` and `siunitx` packages:

[image: screenshot of option 2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.55\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{your caption goes here}
        \label{Tab:Corr}
        \begin{tabular}{p{7cm}c}
            \toprule
            \textbf{A - Fator de correção da rotação}                      & \si{\decibel} \\
            \textless 600 rpm                                              & $-5$          \\
            \textgreater 600 rps e \textless 1500 rpm                      & $-2$          \\
            \textgreater 1500 rpm                                          & $0$           \\ \midrule
            \textbf{B - Fator de correção do combustível}                  & \si{\decibel} \\
            Diesel e gás natural                                           & $0$           \\
            Gás natural                                                    & $-3$          \\ \midrule
            \textbf{C - Fator de disposição dos cilindros}                 & \si{\decibel} \\
            Em linha                                                       & $0$           \\
            Em V e Radial                                                  & $-1$          \\ \midrule
            \textbf{D - Fator de correção de admissão e ar}                & \si{\decibel} \\
            Admissão de ar para o roots blower não dutada e não silenciada & $+3$          \\
            Outros tipos de admissão (com ou sem turbo compressor)         & $0$           \\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.35\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{your other caption}
        \label{Tab:Exaust}
        \begin{tabular}{ S >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} }
            \toprule
            {\parbox{2cm}{Frequência central da banda de oitava [\si{\hertz}]}} & Correção ruído de Exaustão [\si{\decibel}] & Correção ruído de Admissão [\si{\decibel}] \\
            \midrule
            31,5                                                                & $-5$                                       & $-4$                                       \\
            63                                                                  & $-9$                                       & $-11$                                      \\
            125                                                                 & $-3$                                       & $-13$                                      \\
            250                                                                 & $-7$                                       & $-13$                                      \\
            5.00                                                                & $-15$                                      & $-12$                                      \\
            1.000                                                               & $-19$                                      & $-9$                                       \\
            2.000                                                               & $-25$                                      & $-8$                                       \\
            4.000                                                               & $-35$                                      & $-9$                                       \\
            8.000                                                               & $-43$                                      & $-17$                                      \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Other notes

1. If the margins of your document are not wide enough, then you can load the `changepage` package and then use the `adjustwidth` environment:

```
    \begin{table}
         \begin{adjustwidth}{<left offset>}{<right offset>}
          ... 
          ...
          \end{adjustwidth}
     \end{table}
```

2. If you don't wish to use the `table` environment (perhaps you don't wish your tables to float), then you can load the caption package, and then use `\captionof{table}{your caption goes here}`:

```
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.55\textwidth}
              \centering
          \captionof{table}{your caption goes here}
```

Comment: I really appreciated the thoroughness of your answer! Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome :) happy texing, and welcome to the site :)